# How to Resolve; tesseract: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory?

Tags: ruby, heroku, tesseract

When I process an image with the [RTesseract gem](https://github.com/dannnylo/rtesseract) using this [tesseract build pack](https://github.com/oswellchan/heroku-buildpack-tesseract) as such in my Rails app using the Heroku 18 Stack:

```
path = File.expand_path('app/assets/images/chicken_adobo_recipe.jpg')
# => "/app/app/assets/images/chicken_adobo_recipe.jpg"
image = RTesseract.new(path)
# => #<RTesseract:0x000055e949fc9120 @source="/app/app/assets/images/chicken_adobo_recipe.jpg", @config=#<RTesseract::Configuration command="tesseract", debug_file="/dev/null">, @errors=[]>
text = image.to_s
```

My app is experiencing the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):4
RTesseract::Error (tesseract: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

To make sure it is not just an RTesseract gem issue I ran the following command and I'm getting more or less the same error using tesseract:

```
heroku run tesseract app/assets/images/chicken_adobo_recipe.jpg public/output
```

My questions are: why am I experiencing this error? What does the error mean? And also, how can I resolve this error so that I can use tesseract to parse text from images?

This is my Aptfile:

```
tesseract-ocr
tesseract-ocr-eng
```

And this is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.5'

gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.1'
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false
gem 'haml', '~> 5.0', '>= 5.0.4'
gem 'pg', '1.2.3'
gem 'rtesseract', '3.1'
gem "wkhtmltoimage-binary", "0.12.4"

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'awesome_print'
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured this out. To resolve this problem and continue using heroku 18 stack I had to choose a heroku [build pack](https://github.com/pathwaysmedical/heroku-buildpack-tesseract) which installed a more current version -- 4.0 -- of Tesseract.